# How to use OpenCV with Python in Azure App Service?

Tags: python, azure, opencv, azure-web-app-service

I used OpenCV in the App Service of Azure, but an error occurred when installing the extension (pip install opencv-python).

It seems that I can login with SSH on App Service, so after installing the module, login with SSH, and I typed command as following.

```
apt-get install -y libglib2.0-0 libsm6 libxext6
```

Then, I typed command as following.

```
pip install opencv-python
```

I became can use OpenCV in Python by typing the above command.

I thought that it would automatically install pip when writing to requirements.txt and deploying, but the OS initialized after deployment or restart.

I'm setting up type the apt-get command for each deployment.

Please let me know if there is a way to improve it for use OpenCV.

Comment: Could you run your app as an Azure Function? There is a tutorial here https://armiev.com/opencv-with-azure-functions/

Comment: @silent Since OpenCV functions can be processed separately, I think that will solve it. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: But I want to use OpenCV in Azure App Service, because I created a Django application and run it.

Comment: I had the same issue and I found that my solution can use another library than opencv. I was using it for image transformation so I replaced it with scikit-image and every thing is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved by using Azure Web App for Containers.

[Exercise - Create and deploy a web app from a Docker image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/deploy-run-container-app-service/5-exercise-deploy-web-app?pivots=csharp)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The fact of using a custom docker is very painful. But have to know that the azure baked docker images are limited.

Comment: @shadysherif 
Thank you for the detailed information.